# taking physical backup of single database in MYsql

Tags: mysql, database

we need to take backup of a large DB of Mysql . making a script seems to take a lot of time and any error in between requires whole process to restart.

was curious if we can take physical backup of a single Database (taking physical backup of whole MYSQL seems possible).

e.g if there are databases schemas like DB1, DB2 , DB3

can we take physical backup of only DB1

most of the tables are in InnoDB.

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [msyqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html). It lets you dump a database to an SQL file.

Comment: thank you for the answer. but dont want to generate a script. rather simply copy `data files` from one pc and simply paste it in the `data directory` of the other system.
this seems to be possible for the complete mysql instance but not sure for a single database schema

Comment: Ahh. Technically possible, but can cause issues. Look at the documentation for [file per table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html).